# Laravel multiple ManyToMany between same models

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel 5.2 and I have two models : `User` and `Company`

I have a relation ManyToMany between theses two models (with `belongsToMany`)so I get a pivot table `company_user`.

For example, my migration for company is :

```
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('company_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    });
```

How can I duplicate this relation ? I need two ManyToMany between `User` and `Company`.

One is for know if a user is in a company, the other for a subscription system.

Comment: @Andraud What do you mean by duplicating this relation? And you need two ManyToMany between User and Company?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Subscription` model (with a corresponding `subscriptions` table) that has two columns holding foreign key values: `user_id` and `company_id`. You could also store any additional information in this table (such as subscription price, expiry date, etc).

This would make your relation a “has many”, and you could get the subscribed companies with a “has many through” relation:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
    }

    public function subscribedCompanies()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Company::class, Subscription::class);
    }
}
```